# Faction with Neriak in EverQuest 1

Tags: pc, everquest

What is the easiest way to get my faction up with all(...or most) of Neriak?

I need to be able to...

- Buy [hate stones](http://everquest.allakhazam.com/db/item.html?item=23987)
- Bank
- Turn in 50g [Mizr N`Mar](http://eqbeastiary.allakhazam.com/search.html?id=2375) for the rune for the Incandecent Mask Quest

I really don't mind if the occasional NPC aggro's, i can just gate.

Answer (score 3):

You can hand in Red Wine in stacks of four to Lokar T'Biath in the library to increase your Dark Bargainers and Inner/Outer Guards faction.